# 500 Internal Server Error while making HTTP post request in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http

I am building an angular2 app and I am pretty new at angular2. I am trying to make a post request but as an answer from the server, I got ***500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR*** and ***Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500***. However for the post request that I have made without the body, I don't get any error, and I was able to get the correct response from the server.

Here are my service method and corresponding component.ts method.
The code below shows the service.ts file.

```
SomeCoolMethod(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let param = {'name': input.value};
    return this.http.post('fancyURL/SomeCoolMethod', param, options)
        .map(this.extractData);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res.json();
}
```

---

The code below shows the component.ts file.

```
SomeCoolMethod(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.httpService.SomeCoolMethod(input).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```

I know that 500 Internal Server Error is because of the server. But when I make the same request to the server via Advanced Rest Client, it gave no such error. Is there anyone who knows the problem? I think I am setting parameters in an incorrect way but I couldn't find how to fix it. Can you help me with this one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess -- could have something to do with the way you're passing the input HTML element in between the component and service like that? I've never seen that before and it seems potentially a little error prone. Again, that's just a guess

Comment: The error sounds like your app is making a CORS request and it is failing the "preflight check". Is the domain the app is served from the same domain as the server? Also, check the server logs to see why it is issuing the 500 error.

Comment: The question cannot be answered, because the problem is very specific to your backend. You can start solving the problem from server logs. Accidental 500 means that server received some request that wasn't expected. You can check what's sent to the backend in dev tools network tab and then compare that request (headers and body) against successful request that is performed somewhere else (Advanced Rest Client, Postman, etc). There should be differences, and you're the only person who can spot them.

Comment: I am not sure but can you try to send data after JSON stringifying it.  i.e.     this.http.post('fancyURL/SomeCoolMethod', JSON.stringify(param), options).

Comment: @SunilD. The thing is I have another method and its also preflight request, not a simple request and we have fixed it yesterday and it works correctly. However when I checked the network tab in inspect of the web page, only in that function Access control allow origin is * with the other methods that don't work, access control allow origin is localhost : 4200. Do you think that we only fixed one method and the others are still giving CORS issue

Comment: @JaronThatcher, nope, doesn't work. But I think it is correct because I have seen it while people using in couple different places :) Thanks

Comment: @estus I have checked it. In advanced rest client access control allow origin is * while it is local:4200 in my application. I think this is the problematic part.

Comment: @NehilDanış did you solve your problem? I have same issue. My backend works at port:8000 and ng works port:4200.